# Calculated column based on a disconnected slicer

Tags: powerbi

I'm not sure I've summarised this question correctly, so I'll add a description below of the actual problem.

We have a report that displays data for 'jobs'. These jobs have a few relevant date fields on them such as Created Date, Completed Date and Invoice Date. We currently have 3 slicers on the report that work as expected based on these dates.

Users sometimes use all 3 slicers at the same time and end up with all sorts of useless data. No matter how many times we've told them to reset the filters before changing the date slicers, they keep forgetting to do that. 
They also do not want to have 3 separate reports.

We've been tasked with providing them with the following:

1. Something that lets them select what they want to filter on, with the options only being Created, Completed or Invoiced
2. A slicer that works based on the option they selected above.

We've tried creating a calculated column that is set to one of those dates based on the option selected in the disconnected slicer, and then adding a slicer that works off that column, but we aren't having any luck. The values in the calculated column are not correct

This is what we've done in attempting to solve the problem:

**Create a measure that captures the selected value**

```
SelectedMeasure = SELECTEDVALUE('Date Filter Options'[Name],"Created Date")
```

**Create a calculated column to set the appropriate date value**
Please note we're only testing with two out of the three possible values at the moment.

```
Selected Date Filter = if(jobs[SelectedMeasure] = "Created Date", (jobs[Created Date (DateOnly)]), (jobs[Completed Date (DateOnly)]))
```

What we're finding is that the **Selected Date Filter** column does not update with the correct date value, even after we change the slicer and the measure updates as expected.

We're totally stumped - I'm aware we are probably a fair bit away from the correct solution, so any help would be appreciated

---

Not quite sure how to best present the data model, but here are the relevant fields of the 'jobs' table

```
jobNumber: string
jobId: guid
CreatedDate: date
CompletedDate: date
InvoicedDate date
```

The **Date Filter Options** table just consists of one column with these options:

```
"Created Date"
"Completed Date"
"Invoiced Date"
```

Comment: Calculated columns never respond to slicers or other UI controls - they contain static data. Even if they were created with DAX formulas. They can change only upon data reload. You will need to use measures instead. For further help, it's necessary to see your data model.

Comment: For your requirement, I would rather create a measure with some error message and pop that up in a text box at the top of the page based on the user selection.